# Action On Popup Window Close

Tags: javascript, php

Parent Html Code 1.html

```
<a onClick='window.open("1.php","Page","menubar=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, menubar=no, width=200, height=100");return false;'>
```

1.php code:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>';
```

Required:
On closing of popup done by "window.close();", i need to send ajax request from 1.html. how can we do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can call any JavaScript function in the parent window, like this in the .php HTML:

```
window.opener.functionNameOfTheOpenerWindow();
```

Read more here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp